# Android 12's Splash Screen API- Getting white screen after Splash Screen on some below Android 12 devices

Tags: android, android-splashscreen

I have a dedicated SplashScreen Activity and on this activity, there is one API call (once in a lifetime), SDK initialization, setting default values for Firebase RemoteConfig, and routing logic.
It's working fine as expected on some devices, but on some devices, I'm getting a white screen after displaying SplashScreen.

List of devices on which I did testing for it:

1. Samsung s20 fe (Android 12) - **working as expected**
2. OnePlus (Android 11) - **working as expected**
3. MI (Android 11) - **getting a white screen**
4. Moto G5 Plus (Android 8) - **getting a white screen**

Note:
Above mentioned business logic doesn't take much time to get process, please check following logs

```
2022-11-01 15:24:13.146  5905-5905  V  OnCreate
2022-11-01 15:24:13.177  5905-5905  V  SplashScreen.installSplashScreen
2022-11-01 15:24:13.275  5905-5905  V  setKeepOnScreenCondition
2022-11-01 15:24:13.282  5905-5905  V  onTaskComplete
2022-11-01 15:24:13.297  5905-5905  V  nextScreen
2022-11-01 15:24:13.315  5905-5905  V  User details is not null in SplashScreen
2022-11-01 15:24:18.716  5905-5905  V  onDestroy
```

Manifest File

```
   <activity
        android:name=".splashscreen.SplashScreenActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.App.Starting">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

value/styles

```
<style name="Theme.App.Starting" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
    <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/white</item>
    <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/ic_impact</item>
    <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimationDuration">500</item>
    <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/AppTheme</item>
</style>
```

value/styles (v31)

```
<style name="Theme.App.Starting" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
    <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/white</item>
    <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/ic_impact_anim</item>
    <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimationDuration">1000</item>
    <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/AppTheme</item>
</style>
```

SplashScreenActivity

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    SplashScreen splashScreen = SplashScreen.installSplashScreen(this);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    splashScreen.setKeepOnScreenCondition(() -> true);
    Utils.initThirdPartySdk();
    initiateRemoteConfig();
}

//at last calling nextScreen()
 private void nextScreen() {
        Timber.v("nextScreen");
        boolean userLogin = MainApplication.isUserLoggedIn();
        if (userLogin) {
            Timber.v("User details is not null in SplashScreen");
            showMainActivity();
        } else {
            Timber.w("User details is null in SplashScreen, opening LoginActivity");
            showLoginActivity();
        }
        finish();
    }

private void showMainActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: its could be the 2 seconds window during cold start, or this https://www.ittybittyapps.com/blog/2022-10-19-navigation-compose/. Or you need to optimise app start time... check the docs for this.     

This should clarify this issue.. https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/why-should-you-always-test-compose-performance-in-release-4168dd0f2c71

Comment: This couldalso help someone https://joebirch.co/android/exploring-android-12-splash-screen/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was about switching activity, so removing the following line of code for calling MainActivity will solve the problem.

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

Comment: sorry, not work for me